# Java Embed Twitch Video

Tags: java, html, swing, video

I am currently working on a Java program that displays the chat and video of a twitch stream. I already have the chat working, but I'm not sure how to get the video. `http://www.twitch.tv/CHANNEL_NAME/embed` and `http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=CHANNEL_NAME` are both links to the actual video file playing for a specific twitch stream, the first one being a flash file, and the second one being HTML5. I was wondering how I can obtain the video and audio from one of these links and embed it somewhere in my Swing application. thanks!

Comment: In Swing, not very easily.  You could use vlcj, which allows you to embed VLC into a AWT container.  Another option might be to use a JavaFX `WebView`, but you'd have to test it to see if it support video playback via HTML5

Comment: With VLC I don't understand how you can play from a twitch stream. It looks like you can only load the videos from a file path.

Comment: VLC can read URL streams, but I don't know if it will play twitch

Comment: The only other link I have is for HTML5. Maybe there are other links I can find for other video formats. I look into it, but I'm still not sure how VLC can read URL streams, as I haven't seen an example of how it would be used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86743/discussion-between-fatal-cubez-and-madprogrammer).